# How to I find and jump to word in :tselect results?

Tags: vim, find, definition, ctags

I'm using VIM and Ctags, and when I want to jump to a definition I have a shortcut for :tselect. When the window with different matches opens, I would like to find some word with '/' but unfortunately that isn't working. Is that possible at all? Or, is there a better way than using Ctags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That window is not a regular window; it's just the command-line, where normal mode commands can't be used.

But you could use `:ltag` to populate the location list of the current window:

```
:ltag foo
:lwindow
/pattern
```

Here is a quick mapping that should make all that easier:

```
:nnoremap <key> :ltag  <bar>lwindow<S-Left><Left>
```

and a gifcast:

[image]

Comment: Not sure why, but `:cwindow` didn't work for me. However, I did what you've done in the cast with `lwindow` and this worked. `:ltag searchString |lwindow`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions in the answser, I replaced the Ctrl+] with this:

```
nnoremap <C-]> :ltag <c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr><bar>lwindow<CR>
```

Now able to search through the results. Sweet :)